# How to import maven project into eclipse in ubuntu machine (Project is shared as zip file)

Tags: maven

Tried
file -> new -> project -> maven project -> selected the extracted project file from eclipse workspace

Error message displayed

A pom.xml file already exists in destination folder

Tried
file -> new -> project -> maven project -> selected the extracted project file from eclipse workspace

A pom.xml file already exists in destination folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQLJw.png)

Comment: Please, do not post images of error messages and proofread before posting, see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).